# Best Practices for working with many threads / tasks in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In my WPF application, I have a lot of Threads running in my back-end.
I create them via the following syntax:

```
_longRunningThread = new Thread(WorkerOperation);
_longRunningThread.Start();
```

Or

```
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                   //long running operations
            }
```

And then in the front-end of my WPF application, I have my UI Thread that needs to update my UI elements (visibility, change color, change to Enable/Disable, add/remove items from data grid and etc.).

The threads / tasks in the back-end raise event handlers that the UI is registered to. 
When the UI listener is called, I'm in the context of the invoking thread / task (that has been invoked in the back-end), so when I need to update the UI elements (within the UI listener) , I have to context switch to the UI thread. I do that via the following syntax:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(UpdateUiElementsMethod);
```

As far as I understand, this puts the UpdateUiElementsMethod on the queue of the UI Thread, and then (if I don't handle priorities for the queue), it ***synchronously*** executes the actions that were added to the queue.

But... because we have only one UI thread, and event handlers that are raised from too many threads / tasks in the back-end, the queue of the UI thread gets overflooded, so that there might be a few seconds that are passed between raising the event handler in the back-end thread / task and the actual execution of the UI element's update within the UI Thread in the UI listener.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke
```

also does not solve anything: The UI queue does not get overflooded, but if the UI thread is busy, it will take time for the actual action that is invoked to start executing (the context switch to the UI thread will take time) and also, meanwhile, it will block the caller thread (that was created in the back-end) until UI task is completed (until the context is switched to the UI Thread and the action of updating UI elements is executed), so using it may have negative effect on my back-end thread (that is blocked, until the context switch to the UI thread is completed and the action is executed).

Do I have any alternatives or best practices that I can apply in a WPF application in which the UI is needed to be updated from a lot of threads / tasks? 
My goal is of course minimizing the time between raising the event by the back-end thread and the actual UI update in the UI thread.

I'm basically looking for some solution before I start working on reducing the tasks / threads in my app OR reducing the amount of context switches between the back-end threads and the UI thread.

Comment: Simply do not fire so many events, e.g. not more than 10 or 20 per second or so. Otherwise append actions to a queue and periodically read the queue in the UI thread and handle all queued action at once.

Comment: Also don't use threads in C#, the overhead of all your context switches could be killing performance in ways you don't realize. Stephen Cleary's `Concurrency in C# Cookbook` is the unofficial authority on this stuff, here's what it has to to say: "As soon as you type new Thread(), it’s over; your project already has legacy code". Also: "...the Thread and BackgroundWorker types are not covered at all in this book. They have had their time, and that time is over."

Comment: I think you have a fundamental design issue in your app.  You have so much processing going on it's results are trying to change the UI too fast? That often means the user cannot themselves process the changes. Should this all even be in the one solution anyhow? Maybe you should be considering windows services for the processing and some sort of enterprise service bus architecture.